# Mongo Replica instances running

Tags: mongodb, set, bin, replicaset

I try 3 mongo instances config replica set on my localhost, so I run mongod from global Path variable set in window for all 3 instances.

Is it good/best practice or do I have to run *monngod* from `/bin/mongod` every folder where I have mongo installed?

I think its not neccessary create 3 bins folder, only one folder and run one *mongod* and mongo shell `--port XXXXX`, its ok to use it this way?

Comment: It's not good practice to run more than one instance of MongoDB on one machine at all. That said, you definitely *don't* need to install it to multiple bin locations; just the one installation will do OK, with separate configurations.

Comment: i though so, I do it only for local replica tests, sure i will have three servers and one for app